# Counting level of recursion in Racket

Tags: parsing, racket

I am working on a document structure, which includes chapters, subchapters etc. Each "section" I would like to mark with different HTML header tag, so title would be in `<h1>`, chapters in `<h2>`, subchapters in `<h3>` and so on. Structrures that I am working on are:

```
(struct section     (title text next) #:transparent) ; title is a string, text is list of paragraphs, next is following list of sections
(struct paragraph   (text)            #:transparent) ; text is a string
(struct image       (file alt)        #:transparent)
```

I would like to transform a document declared with such structures to be made of headers I mentioned earlier and I wrote such function:

```
(define level 0)
(define (inc-nest-level)
  (set! level (+ level 1)))

(define (doc->txt t)
  (match t
    [(image img txt)    (tag-img img txt)]
    [(paragraph x)      (tag-p x)]
    ;; p1 = title, p2 = text (list of paragraphs), p3 = next (list of subsections)
    [(section p1 p2 p3) (inc-nest-level)
                        (string-append (tag-header p1 level) "\n"
                                       (strings-list->string (map doc->txt p2)) "\n"
                                       (strings-list->string (map doc->txt p3)) "\n")]))
```

The problem is, that when I parse a document to include HTML tags, each header `<h*>` is wrong, as it does not count levels of recursion, but number of occurences of any header,  which means that parsing this document:

```
(define test-doc
  (section "test-doc-title"
           (list (paragraph "title-paragraph-1")
                 (paragraph "title-paragraph-2")
                 (paragraph "title-paragraph-3")
                 (image     "image3.jpg" "alternate text")
                 (paragraph "title-paragraph-4"))
           (list (section "test-doc-chapter-1"
                          (list (paragraph "ch-1-paragraph-1")
                                (paragraph "ch-1-paragraph-2")
                                (paragraph "ch-1-paragraph-3"))
                          null)
                 (section "test-doc-chapter-2"
                          (list (paragraph "ch-2-paragraph-1"))
                          (list (section "test-doc-chapter-2-sub-1"
                                         (list (paragraph "ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-1")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-2")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-3")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-4")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-5")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-6"))
                                         null)
                                (section "test-doc-chapter-2-sub-2"
                                         (list (paragraph "ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-1")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-2")
                                               (paragraph "ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-3"))
                                         null)))
                 (section "test-doc-chapter-3"
                          (list (paragraph "ch-3-paragraph-1")
                                (paragraph "ch-3-paragraph-2"))
                          null))))
```

returns following answer (with `(display (doc->txt test-doc))` function:

```
<h1>test-doc-title</h1>
<p>title-paragraph-1</p>
<p>title-paragraph-2</p>
<p>title-paragraph-3</p>
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="alternate text"><br><p>title-paragraph-4</p>

<h2>test-doc-chapter-1</h2>
<p>ch-1-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-1-paragraph-2</p>
<p>ch-1-paragraph-3</p>


<h3>test-doc-chapter-2</h3>
<p>ch-2-paragraph-1</p>

<h4>test-doc-chapter-2-sub-1</h4>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-2</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-3</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-4</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-5</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-6</p>


<h5>test-doc-chapter-2-sub-2</h5>
<p>ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-2</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-3</p>



<h6>test-doc-chapter-3</h6>
<p>ch-3-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-3-paragraph-2</p>
```

The problem is, that I would like to count each level of reccursion independently, so I would get something like:

```
<h1>test-doc-title</h1>
<p>title-paragraph-1</p>
<p>title-paragraph-2</p>
<p>title-paragraph-3</p>
<img src="image3.jpg" alt="alternate text"><br><p>title-paragraph-4</p>

<h2>test-doc-chapter-1</h2>
<p>ch-1-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-1-paragraph-2</p>
<p>ch-1-paragraph-3</p>


<h2>test-doc-chapter-2</h2>
<p>ch-2-paragraph-1</p>

<h3>test-doc-chapter-2-sub-1</h3>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-2</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-3</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-4</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-5</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-1-paragraph-6</p>


<h3>test-doc-chapter-2-sub-2</h3>
<p>ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-2</p>
<p>ch-2-sub-2-paragraph-3</p>



<h2>test-doc-chapter-3</h2>
<p>ch-3-paragraph-1</p>
<p>ch-3-paragraph-2</p>
```

I need help with remaking `doc->txt` function, so it would parse headers the way I mentioned.

Edit: `tag-header` function is defined as:

```
(define (tag-header title level)
  (if (> level 6)
      (set! level 6)
      void)
  (let [(lvl (number->string level))]
    (string-append "<h" lvl ">" title "</h" lvl ">")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of struggles, I finally got that to work. What I needed to do, was to define a helper function `map-2`, which takes as an input function `f`, list `xs` and a "nest-level counter" `lvl`, so in every deeper section it applies `f` to every element of the list and saves the nest-level counter. Final function:

```
(define (doc->txt t)
  (define (map-2 f xs lvl)
    (if (null? xs)
        null
        (cons (f (car xs) lvl)
              (map-2 f (cdr xs) lvl))))
  (define (aux t l) ;; l stands for level of nests, so headers are smaller with each level
    (match t
      [(image img txt)    (tag-img img txt)]
      [(paragraph x)      (tag-p x)]
      ;; p1 = title, p2 = text (list of paragraphs), p3 = next (list of subsections)
      [(section p1 p2 p3) (string-append (tag-header p1 l) "\n"
                                                (strings-list->string (map-2 aux p2 (add1 l))) "\n"
                                                (strings-list->string (map-2 aux p3 (add1 l))) "\n")]))
  (aux t 1))
```